# Logging data to database with EnterpriseLibrary

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

Hi I am trying to integrate EnterprisLibrary Logging block into my application using a database as storage.Here is what I have so far:

I have runed the scripts for the database and have created a database called e-shop.Logging
that has 3 tables Category , CategoryLog and Log.

I have created this configuration on my web config:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In my code I have this configuration class:

```
public static class LoggerBootstrapper
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory());

        Logger.SetLogWriter(new LogWriterFactory().Create());
    }
}
```

This is called in Global.asax in my WebApi project.

And this is the class that I use in my entire application:

```
[InjectorRegistration(typeof(IExceptionLogger))]
public class ExceptionLogger : IExceptionLogger
{
    public void LogServerException(Exception exception)
    {
        string logger = LoggerCategories.ServerLogger.ToString();
        Logger.Write(exception, LoggerCategories.ServerLogger.ToString());
    }

    public void LogClientException(Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Write(exception, LoggerCategories.ClientLogger.ToString());
    }
}
 public enum LoggerCategories
{
    ServerLogger,
    ClientLogger
}
```

When I call the LogServerException or LogClientException , the data get's stored in the Log table but nothing get's stored in the Category and CategoryLog tables.

I first asummed that I had to add the categories myself so I added this two categories:
ServerLogger
ClientLogger

Of course it did not work.I have seen this configured that when you add a category it automaticly get's added to the Category table and when an exception get's added the mapping beetween Category and Log is automaticly done threw CategoryLog.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?
Why when I am adding an exception data get's added only in  the log table and the other two table are not updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going threw the XML I realized that the stored procedure ressposible for adding the category was not set right.I had it set to ServerLogger an the actual stored procedure name was AddCateogry.